# iOS UITableView reload

Tags: ios, uitableview

I ran into a piece of code for UITableView, click on of the cell and it reloads but what exactly is the data source? I am not too clear on this.

```
  [xTable reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:button.tag inSection:0],nil] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
```

Comment: write down the whole code of that function

Answer (score 2):

It runs the following "tableview cellForRowAtIndexPath" method and loads the updated information for the specified cell.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

DataSource is a protocol in the UITableView that defines a set of messages that the UITableView sends to this object(datasource)
These messages returns data that is filled inside the tableview 
Some messages are like:

`numberOfRowsInSection`: you will return the number of rows this table will have
`cellForRowAtIndex`: you will return here the UITableViewCell object for the given index
`numberOfSectionsInTableView`:  you will return the number of sections this table will have

How this works
in your class you will call `tableView.dataSource = self;`
`[UITableView reloadData]` gets executed, the datasource messages get sent to the datasource object (in this example it will be the object set on the right side of `.dataSource = self;`

table view will use these consecutive calls to build the table view itself

For further indepth reading please rever to

[Simple tutorial on how to implement the datasource in iphone](http://www.iosdevnotes.com/2011/10/uitableview-tutorial/)

[Data Source design pattern](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1398618)

Comment: [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:button.tag inSection:0],nil] means loads a NSArray of objects which come from itslef?  It sounds kind of like circular reasoning.